# Running parallel python programs on HPC

Tags: python, distributed, hpc

I used to make some parallelizable computations using python on a server, now I want to migrate to an HPC working on SLURM, but I believe I have some conceptual issues.

My computation needs matrices and parameters (as dictionary) that are same for all runs, and some input parameters that differ. So it basically looks like:

```
def evaluate(inp, matrices, params):
    .....
    return output

load matrices, create params dict...
inputs = [(k, matrices, params) for k in input_parameters]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n) as pool:
    results =pool.starmap(evaluate,inputs)
save_results(results)
```

and a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J ****     
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40
#SBATCH --mem=500M              
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00 
#SBATCH --partition=standard
module load python
source $HOME/env/bin/activate
python3 main.py
```

So my problem here is, on a single node, even though processes are active, they get %0 CPU, and waits until SLURM exits the job due to over-time, and when I have tried to use multiprocessing.get_context.Pool instead of multiprocessing.Pool, the code runs, and never finishes. I don't quite see what the problem can be?

Also if I want to execute this program on multiple nodes, I understand that I need to bind MPI's, and mpi4py or ray can be used for this purpose. Is this also the case for a single node job?

Answer (score 0):

Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package is used for spawning subprocesses on a single node. This means your program starts with 1 process which may then spawn many subprocesses.

Workload managers like [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html), on the other hand, are used to execute parallel work across nodes. This allows you to run your program many times across many nodes. Since each program is an independent process in this case, you'll likely need interprocess communication (like [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) to facilitate parallelism.